# How to do change detection between two Landsat scenes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, change-detection

I want to do change detection and calculate the changes step by step using two images: the first image Landsat 1986, and the second Landsat 2000.

Actually I have used image differences in ArcMap and I get raster values for RGB ranging from 213 to -69.  What I should do to make this result more meaningful?

Answer (score 3):

You could square your differences, and then normalize them to the range from 0 to 1 by dividing with the largest occurring value. This can be done using the Raster Calculator, which is documented here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 .

Depending on what you want to do, you can then define a threshold with a meaning of "everything where my change value is below the threshold is unchanged, everything above is probably changed".

Comment: What I am really stuck with is how to get  0 to 1 value, My I ask you which tool i can use in ARCMap 10.2?

Comment: Try the [Divide tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000008r000000) with your max as division value.

Comment: Please more details or any one has a detailed tutorial about change detection using image differencing with detailed of how to calculate the areas of changes..